# Type mismatch and underlying type

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

My code throws an error that I don't really understand.
The code is supposed to check the list for pairs that satisfy the predicate and return it as a set.

[error] found : bH.type (with underlying type B) [error] required: B

Can I get an explanation of why exactly that occurs and how to fix it?

```
object Zad1 {
      type Pred[T] = T => Boolean
    
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    
      }
      def znajdz[A,B](alist: List[A],blist: List[B])(pred: Pred[(A,B)]): Set[(A,B)] = {
        @annotation.tailrec
        def assist[A,B](alist: List[A],blist: List[B],tail: Set[(A,B)]): Set[(A,B)] = {
          (alist,blist) match {
            case (aH::aT,bH::bT) =>  (pred((aH,bH))) match {
              case true => assist(aT,bT,Set((aH,bH))++tail)
              case false => assist(aT,bT,tail)
              }
            case _ => tail 
          }
        }
          assist(alist,blist,Set.empty)
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Method `assist()` is shadowing (redefining) types `A` and `B`. Remove the `[A,B]` part and it should compile.

Comment: -Xlint will warn about shadowing type vars.